# how to change values nested array value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1522
            [image] => 1465458797-sug.jpg,1465458797-rajdhanee.jpg
            [user_name] => Suganya
            [thumbnail] => Taylor_Otwell_.jpg
            [feature_product] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 151
            [image] => 1465296555-14.jpg
            [user_name] => Sugan
            [thumbnail] => sug.jpg
            [feature_product] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [image] => 1401101483-best-kitchen-appliances.jpg,1401101483-home-appliance_laundry.jpg,1401101483-kitchen-appliances-contemporary.jpg
            [user_name] => admin
            [thumbnail] => images_(1).jpg
            [feature_product] => 0
        )

)
```

And I need the resultant array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1522
            [image] => www.example.com/1465458797-sug.jpg,www.example.com/1465458797-rajdhanee.jpg
            [user_name] => Suganya
            [thumbnail] => Taylor_Otwell_.jpg
            [feature_product] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 151
            [image] => www.example.com/1465296555-14.jpg
            [user_name] => Sugan
            [thumbnail] => sug.jpg
            [feature_product] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [image] => www.example.com/1401101483-best-kitchen-appliances.jpg,www.example.com/1401101483-home-appliance_laundry.jpg,www.example.com/1401101483-kitchen-appliances-contemporary.jpg
            [user_name] => admin
            [thumbnail] => images_(1).jpg
            [feature_product] => 0
        )

)
```

i.e.,

The image values must append the given url into it...

I tried something like follows,But it din't work for me..

```
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $req_i=0;
        $img = explode(',', $value->image);
           if(!isset($image)){
                $image = $url.$image_url.$img[$req_i];
           } else {
                // $value->image = $url.'images/'.$default_image;
                $image = $image.','.$url.$image_url.$img[$req_i];
           }
           $req_i++;
    }
    print_r($image);echo "<br>";exit;
```

Here I'm just try to print those values..

But it returns value like this.

**`www.example.com/1465458797-sug.jpg,www.example.com/1465296555-14.jpg,www.example.com/1401101483-best-kitchen-appliances.jpg`**

Somebody help me that how could I reach this :(

Thank you,

Comment: what do you want to return ? I do not understand. Have you tried to decode the json before working with it? Try json_decode($yourJson, true), it will return an  associative array.

Comment: Actually what I need to do is append the url before all the images in comma seperated manner..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it guyzz...

Finally I did it..

```
    $url = www.example.com/
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $image = array();
        $img = explode(',', $value->image);
        foreach ($img as $key_in => $value_in) {
            $image[] = $url.$value_in;
        }
        $value->image = implode(',', $image);
    }
```

And I get final array as

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1522
            [image] => www.example.com/1465458797-sug.jpg,www.example.com/1465458797-rajdhanee.jpg
            [user_name] => Suganya
            [thumbnail] => Taylor_Otwell_.jpg
            [feature_product] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 151
            [image] => www.example.com/1465296555-14.jpg
            [user_name] => Sugan
            [thumbnail] => sug.jpg
            [feature_product] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [image] => www.example.com/1401101483-best-kitchen-appliances.jpg,www.example.com/1401101483-home-appliance_laundry.jpg,www.example.com/1401101483-kitchen-appliances-contemporary.jpg
            [user_name] => admin
            [thumbnail] => images_(1).jpg
            [feature_product] => 0
        )

)
```

Thank you everyone who are all trying to help me..
 :)

Answer (score 0):

im assuiming your using this to display in a view why dont you just pass it in the view?

`<image src="www.example.com/<?php 'echo Your image path '; ?>  "`

Comment: Sorry Reuben Gomes I think you misunderstand my question..
I'm doing webservice,For that I need to send all values in the json_encode() format for that purpose only I'm asking this question here..

Comment: if(!isset($image)){  shouldnt it be $img